# Invalid Operation Exception from Dapper QueryMultipleAsync

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, dapper

I have a `SqlConnectionWrapper` class built on top of Dapper with the purpose of encapsulating some error handling and a retry mechanism. The relevant method of the class is this:

```
public async Task<SqlMapper.GridReader> QueryMultipleAsync(
    string procedure,
    object? parameters = null,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var attempt = 1;
    var attempts = Options.Attempts < 1 ? int.MaxValue : Options.Attempts;

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            await using var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringHelper.ToString());

            return await sqlConnection.QueryMultipleAsync(
                procedure,
                parameters,
                commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            Logger.LogError(
                e,
                "Failed to query procedure '{procedure}' for multiple result sets.\n\nParameters:\n\n{parameters}\n\nAttempt #{attempt} of {attempts}.",
                procedure,
                JsonSerializer.Serialize(parameters, JsonSerializerOptions),
                attempt,
                attempts);

            if (attempt++ == attempts || cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Logger.LogDebug(cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested ? "Cancellation is requested. Throwing..." : "Exceeded maximum attempts. Throwing...");
                throw;
            }

            await Task.Delay(Options.RetryDelay, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

The specific situation I'm trying to use this for is when I briefly lose connection to my database due to a backup, reboot, etc. The `SqlException` is caught as expected, but then the next attempt throws an `InvalidOperationException`:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: BeginExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is open.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__126_0(Task`1 result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.QueryMultipleAsync(IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition command) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.Async.cs:line 1039
   at SqlConnectionWrapper.QueryMultipleAsync(String procedure, Object parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

"...requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is open," really throws me for a loop. How can I prevent this exception?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looping while the connection is still open from the previous call.  Rather than a loop, I'd use a little recursion to handle the retries:

```
    public async Task<SqlMapper.GridReader> QueryMultipleAsync(
        string procedure,
        object? parameters = null,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var attempts = Options.Attempts < 1 ? int.MaxValue : Options.Attempts;
        return await QueryMultipleAsyncWithRetry(attempts, procedure, parameters, cancellationToken);
    }

    public async Task<SqlMapper.GridReader> QueryMultipleAsyncWithRetry(
        int retriesLeft,
        string procedure,
        object? parameters = null,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        if (retriesLeft <= 0)
            return null;
        try
        {
            await using var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringHelper.ToString());

            return await sqlConnection.QueryMultipleAsync(
                procedure,
                parameters,
                commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            Logger.LogError(
                e,
                "Failed to query procedure '{procedure}' for multiple result sets.\n\nParameters:\n\n{parameters}\n\nAttempt #{attempt} of {attempts}.",
                procedure,
                JsonSerializer.Serialize(parameters, JsonSerializerOptions),
                attempt,
            attempts);

            if (attempt++ == attempts || cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Logger.LogDebug(cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested ? "Cancellation is requested. Throwing..." : "Exceeded maximum attempts. Throwing...");
                throw;
            }

            await Task.Delay(Options.RetryDelay, cancellationToken);
            return await QueryMultipleAsyncWithRetry(--retriesLeft, procedure, parameters, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't `await using` clean up the connection before the next iteration of the loop?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure.  But, it's definitely odd to loop around an await.  Like I said before, I'd rearchitect the logic to eliminate the loop.

Comment: Why is it "definitely odd to loop around an await?" How is using recursion with await any different than looping, except for the increased stack usage? The loop could theoretically run forever if that was the desired behavior; the recursion will fail due to a stack overflow at some point.

Comment: I'm thinking that the loop is causing the connection to not be disposed, as it would naturally when exiting the function.  The method needs to complete for the connection to go out of scope and get disposed properly.  So, maybe recursive calls would have the same effect.  Possibly try moving all the connection code (including the try-catch) into a separate function, then loop (or recurse) over that function.